# Changing Color and Fonts of all Reports on the reportserver

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

We have newly just migrated to SSRS 2016 and the company wants to change the color and font display of all the reports for consistency sake?.

Is there an automated way of defining the fonts & colors of all reports on the reportserver without having to make the change at the report level (rdl).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this at the server level. An RDL is just an XML file (open it in any text editor to check it out) so in theory you could try to find/replace across all the RDL files (after you downloaded them to your local machine). I imagine it would be a hard find/replace to get right though. If you are really daring you could try updating the dbo.Catalog table directly in the ReportServer database but that is not a recommended approach as chances are you will break the reports.

Comment: If you are really daring you can also define properties in a table and then include a reference to that on your reports to dynamically control formatting.